# How do I use drop down to link to a file?

Tags: xhtml

I have a request for using drop down boxes for links to documents on a website.

Is it possible to do this? The code I am using is like this:

```
<select name="EN9036">
  <option value="tds"><a href="doc1.pdf">Tech Data Sheet</a></option>
  <option value="msds"><a href="doc2.pdf">MSDS</a></option>
</select>
```

Only problem is that it doesn't work. Therefore I am completely open to suggestions and new ways of seeing the world.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jukka has [a good guide on the subject](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html).

The section about better alternatives to that horrible bit of design is especially worth reading.